# It's Winter. Florida's not participating

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[image: It's Winter, but Florida's not participating.]

Is Florida in violation of the passuk in Bereishis 8:22:

> עֹ֖ד כָּל־יְמֵ֣י הָאָ֑רֶץ זֶ֡רַע וְ֠קָצִיר וְקֹ֨ר וָחֹ֜ם וְקַ֧יִץ וָחֹ֛רֶף וְי֥וֹם וָלַ֖יְלָה לֹ֥א יִשְׁבֹּֽתוּ׃
>
> Furthermore, all the days of the land: seed time and harvest, **cold** and hot, summer and **winter**, day and night shall not rest.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: As a resident Floridian I can tell you that I miss the days back outside of Florida when I actually needed a coat during the winter.

Comment: Well, March in NY area can be fickle. If you really miss snow that much, I'll gladly exchange my home with yours next winter providing that you come to NY just prior to any snowstorm with prediction of at least 10 inches, and you have to shovel my driveway. Deal or no deal? (Just remember, we have the same initials!)

Comment: The ultimate proof that Florida doesn't exist.

Comment: BTW, the arrow is pointing to Tampa, not Florida. And I guess they put Tampa on the wrong coast! What's the matter with these guys???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_Florida) article explains in detail the unusual climate of Florida. In particular, it explains why Southern Florida, in particular, barely gets to the freezing point or below even when severe cold fronts bring winter conditions to central Florida. You can read the article for the particulars. It explains why Florida "doesn't participate" in winter.

Despite that, Florida is not in any violation of the verse that you cited. The end of the verse says, "It shall not rest." Being a Floridian, you know very well that the climate in Florida and Floridians never rest from the weather. Florida seems to get every type of "freaky" weather in existence. The panhandle does get snow; the central part of the state gets below freezing weather at least once every winter and that ruins the orange crop. (Trust me - I abhor spending more for orange juice!) The winter is supposed to be dry, huh? It seems that Florida got walloped with flooding storms and massive tornadoes in January 2016! (My friend who lives in Delray texted me in a panic a few times in 3 days.) Then, you have to worry about nearly every tropical storm / hurricane in existence, and you guys can get it from both directions! From the Gulf OR the Atlantic.

In short, Florida, never rests and Floridians never rest from worrying about the climate. So, no, Florida is not in any violation, even if, occasionally, you don't want to participate in winter. It seems that this year, or now, you have an exception.

Comment: Coming back to this a year later, having survived Hurricane Irma, I'm starting to think you might have jinxed us with that last line.

Comment: @DonielF Oy! I'm sure that was no fun. Sandy was no fun for us, esp. for my wife who's name is ... Sandy :-( You might want to think about moving to NYC. Snowstorms are much easier to deal with than hurricanes.